# run defined function spyder

Tags: python, function, spyder

I am using spyder as python editor.
At the beginning of my code I import the functions that I wrote, for example

```
from my_functions_file import function_1
```

It happens that when I modify `function_1` in the file `my_functions_file.py` I have to close and re open spyder to have it updated (i.e. running the update version).

Is there a way to run the updated version without re-start spyder?
I tried running again the line

`from my_functions_file import function_1`

Comment: Odd, once you save `my_functions_file` it is reloaded on next import.

Comment: Try this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681504/spyder-not-updating-pyc-files

Answer (score 0):

This is done automatically by Spyder as long as you run the file that contains your imports with **F5** or from the menu

```
Run > Run
```