# Spyder not updating .pyc files

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, spyder

I have created the class in separate code in Python (Spyder). Then I import the class into main code using:

```
from othercode import classxy
```

Then the .pyc file is created in **pychache**' folder. However when I change something in the class, save it and import it once again in main code, then the .pyc file is not updated and main code is still working with old version of class. I have to delete the .pyc file for class and turn off and turn on the Spyder which is kinda dumb. Is there something I'm missing? When I run the main code in Anaconda prompt, everything is working as it should, just Spyder is behaving strange.

Comment: Are you doing this in the terminal in an interactive python session?

Comment: In Python IDE called Spyder together with Anaconda

Comment: That didn't answer my question at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) To have your code updated after every change to it, you need to run these commands before running your code in our IPython consoles (but only once):

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload
In [2]: %autoreload 2
```

Comment: Great! We're planning to run those line by default in the future.